# Accepting reviews (opinions) instead of facts that work

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

When should a answer be "accepted" since in Code Review it is a opinion review, and not a fact-based answer that points to a problem in a code (or something like that), and any opinion can be good enough?

For example, user A says a opinion and user B says another in their reviews. But which one must be chosen The One? After all, opinions are indifferent to each other when rated by someone neutral to them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The asker should mark as accepted the answer which they found most constructive.

It's not an objective thing (on any of the Stack Exchange sites even).  It is entirely the opinion of the asker.  It's a super upvote, if you will.

Answer (score 5):

While Code Review answers can deal with opinions, they often deal with accepted best practices, bug fixes, and other non-opinionated improvements.  As @nhgrif says, accept the one that helped you the most.  Sometimes, this is the answer that covers the most, sometimes it is the one that points out an obscure bug.  It really depends on the circumstances.

Comment: I'd say that in many cases, it really *is* about opinions. I have written comments many times of the form "I like your answer, but do not agree with X because I think Y"

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely This better?